# if string.match() doesn't match, why is execution of google apps script cancelled?

Tags: google-apps-script

if I use the following function within Google Sheets it doesn't return the value "not found".
The logs tell me: "Execution cancelled".

This happens at the line:

```
var found = text.match(re);
```

If I change searchText to "abc" it works like a charme.

```
function example()
{
  var text = "abc cba";
  var searchText = "abcd";

  var re = new RegExp(searchText,"g");

  var found = text.match(re);

  if (found === undefined) { 
    return "not found";
  }
  else {
    return found;
  }
}
```

Why is the script execution cancelled and how can I prevent this behavior without using the regex twice by using e.g. *text.search(re) combined with if* before the *match()* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Cause:

The return value of `string.match` ,

> [An Array whose contents depend on the presence or absence of the global (g) flag, or **null** if no matches are found.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

and

```
null !== undefined
```

So, when it's null, the `else` statement executes and returns null to sheet. <strike>The "execution cancelled" is irrelevant  and probably from old logs</strike>[<sup>issue</sup>](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150669095)

#### Solution:

Use null to compare return value.

#### Snippet:

```
if (found === null) {
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. I didn't expect this.
If I use the debugger it stops at the null return in the mentioned line above. I thought that the script then completely stops. Seems not to be so. A debugger error?

Comment: @Axe I can't reproduce this in the debugger.  It runs without error when I test it.

Comment: if you going step-by-step thru the code with debugger? My google apps integrated debugger cancels everytime the runtime and in the logs appears the "execution cancelled" message ...

Comment: The only way to go step by step is if you marked a breakpoint. Did you put a red dot on the line number?

Comment: yes of course :-) and if I use the step in button it executes the line "var found = text.match(re);" and if it matches I can go to the next step. If it doesn't match the scripts stops and in the logs is the cancelled message ...

Comment: @Axel I was able to reproduce it. Seems like a bug. In any case, a new editor based on vscode is coming soon. So it would be pointless to report it now. PS: Consider accepting the answer, if it solved your problem.