# Google Apps Script V8 assignment to null cancels debugging

Tags: google-apps-script, v8, google-apps-script-editor

A variable assignment to null causes debugging to cancel execution at that line.
Here is a test script that reproduces the problem:

```
function myFunction() {
  var a = "Hallo";
  Logger.log("a=" + a);
  var b = null;
  Logger.log("b=" + b);
}
```

When debugging this script execution is cancelled on line "var b = null;".  Log output is:

```
Mar 11, 2020, 8:52:49 PM    Info    a=Hallo
Mar 11, 2020, 8:52:54 PM    Info    Execution cancelled.
```

The result is the same when stepping over the line and running past the line in debug mode. However, in the latter case a red error message flashes for a moment at the top of the screen that says: "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again."... waiting and retrying makes no difference.
[Tried it again today after Jeff's comment below and was only able to recreate it by stepping over the assignment line in debug mode]

When running the script normally (not in debug) it completes successfully.

Comment: There is another V8 issue related to debug on the Issue Tracker: [https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149636786](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149636786)

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your error, what steps are you following here? I do Run  > Debug function > myFunction

Comment: Thank you for the replies.

Alan, I had a look at that issue and it might be related but I'm not sure to what extent.

Jeff, yes that is how I did it and by stepping from a break point. However, I tried it now again and I couldn't recreate it by just doing Run > Debug function > myFunction.  I could only recreate it by setting a break point and stepping over the line doing the null assignment.

Comment: @Tach You could create a new issue in the issuetracker

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60543633/

Comment: Thank you @TheMaster. The related issue you sent is explaining the same issue since there is also a null assignment with step-debugging. I'm considering creating an issue on issuetracker, but you mentioned that a new vscode based IDE is replacing the current one for Apps Script. Do you know when more-or-less?

Comment: Issuetracker issue is already logged: [issue 150669095](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150669095)

Comment: Yes. IDE is in development. Not sure when they'll release. https://support.google.com/a/table/7539891

Answer (score 2):

I found temporary workaround:

Temporally (just for debugging) remove `var` for variable that takes `null` value.

Be careful: variable without `var` becomes global - so you can accidentally change value of the global variable with the same name.

But without the `var` you will not be able to see your variable in the debugger. So another workaround is to test your variable using `if` statement to see the value in the debugger:

change:

```
  var b = null;
```

temporally (just for debugging) to:

```
  b = null;
  if (b==null){
    var b0='null';
  } else {
    var b0=b;
  }
```

and observe `b0` variable in the debugger