# Why getProperty is crashing?

Tags: google-apps-script

I use this simple script:

```
  var scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var test = scriptProp.getProperty("test");
```

But the execution is terminated at the second line because the property do not exist. I thought getProperty would return null if the property did not exist.

Is it the case ? And if not, how to test the existence of a property ?

Note : I've tested a creation of the same property and it works  well : after that, I can get my property.

Comment: I think that when `test` is not existing, `null` is returned from `scriptProp.getProperty("test")`. And also, when I tested your script, I could confirm that `null` is returned with and without V8. So as a example script for checking whether the key of `test` is included in the script properties, how about this? `const res = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getKeys().filter(e => e == "test")[0];` In this case, when the key of `test` is existing and not existing, `test` and `null` are returned, respectively. If this was not the direction you expect, I apologize for this.

Comment: The debugger doesn't work properly.

Comment: It's very good if null is returned. But after these lines I have others that must manipulate the "test" variable but when I debug the script, it's terminated on the getProperty line of code and do not continue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue. Consider creating a [new issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=823905) in the issuetracker or [starring this related issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150669095), if you think they're sufficiently related.

Related questions:

- [Google Apps Script V8 assignment to null cancels debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60643019/)
- [if string.match() doesn't match, why is execution of google apps script cancelled?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60543633/)